# Find the line integral of $1/(z^2+4)^2$ over region $\gamma$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

I have to find:
$$I=\oint_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{(z^2+4)^2}.$$

$\gamma$ in this case is a circular curve defined by $|z-i|=2$, which is a circle centered at $i$ with radius $2$.  It is clear that the singularity here is $+2i$ and $-2i$, the latter of which is outside the circle.  When a singularity is outside a circle its $0$ so do I just evaluate the one within the circle?  By that would I just add them?

Answer (score 3):

The residue theorem gives that the integral of a meromorphic function $f(z)$ on a simple closed contour $\gamma$, provided that $f(z)$ is regular in a small neighbourhood of $\gamma$, equals $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $f(z)$ at the singularities **inside** $\gamma$. So we have:

$$I=\oint_{|z-i|=2}\frac{dz}{(z^2+4)^2} = 2\pi i\,\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(z^2+4)^2},z=2i\right) $$
and since $z=2i$ is a double pole for the given function it follows that:
$$ I = 2\pi i\cdot\lim_{z\to 2i}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{(z-2i)^2}{(z^2+4)^2}=2\pi i\cdot\lim_{z\to 2i}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{(z+2i)^2}=-4\pi i\cdot\lim_{z\to 2i}\frac{1}{(z+2i)^3}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{16}}.$$

Comment: Did you get $(z-2i)^2$ because of the fact that z=2i is a double pole?

Comment: @cambelot: it follows from $z^2+4=(z+2i)(z-2i)$. The $\frac{d}{dz}$ part is due to the fact that $z=2i$ is a double pole.